# Spring REST API: download file and choose the name and location to save

Tags: java, spring, download, swagger, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to make an immediate download for generated files without saving them in persistent storage.

```
@Operation(
      summary = "Download csv.",
      description = "Download csv.",
      responses = {@ApiResponse(content = @Content(
          mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE))}
  )
  @GetMapping(value = "/download", produces = APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
  public Resource downloadFile(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String s =
        "uuid1\tdata\n" +
        "uuid2\tdata\n" +
        "uuid3\tdata";
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(s.getBytes(), "description");
    return resource;
  }
```

As a result I get a valid download link via Swagger or immediate download via direct request.

**What I want to do:**

1. To pre-set the name and extension for the file, that will be downloaded.
2. I want to get a prompt and choose the place where to save it.

Is it possible to do with the backend only?

Answer (score 1):

`To pre-set the name and extension for the file, that will be downloaded.`

Try injecting an `HttpServletResponse` object into your controller method and set a header on that response-object like this:

`response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=<yourfilename>.<yourextension>");`

Format the string however you'd like if you want the filename to be dynamic or depend on some attributes.

Someone else would have to answer your second point, as I haven't encountered it yet.

edit: typo